# How can I upload multiple images on single file upload using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I am creating a program where I want to have a single file upload to select multiple images and save it to the database. I'm not that so genius in coding, but I understand programming.

Here's what I did so far,

**Controller/upload.php**

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->helper('date');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('v_page/header_view');
        $this->load->view('v_document/upload_view', array('error' => ' ' ));
        $this->load->view('v_page/footer_view');
    }

    public function do_upload() {
        //print_r($_FILES);
        $config = array(
            'upload_path'   => './public/img/uploads',
            'upload_url'    => base_url().'public/img/uploads',
            'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
            //'overwrite'     => TRUE,
            'max_size'      => '1000KB',
            'max_width'     => '1024',
            'max_height'    => '768',
            //'encrypt_name'  => true,
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('v_page/header_view');
            $this->load->view('v_document/upload_error', $error);
            $this->load->view('v_document/upload_view');
            $this->load->view('v_page/footer_view');
        } 
        else {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_array = array(
                'image_name'    => $upload_data['file_name'],
                //'description'   => "",
                'date_created'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()),
                'date_modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()),
                'size'          => $upload_data['file_size'],
                'type'          => $upload_data['image_type'],
                'width'         => $upload_data['image_width'],
                'height'        => $upload_data['image_height'],
                'actions'       => "modify",
            );
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db->insert('tbl_image', $file_array);
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('v_document/upload_success', $data);
        }
    }

    public function upload_success() {
        redirect('do_upload', 'refresh');
    }
```

**views/v_document/upload_view.php**

```
<p class="alert alert-info">Upload New Document</p>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<label for="file">Select File To Upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="userfile" multiple="multiple" class="btn btn-file"/>
</br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary"/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**views/v_document/upload_error.php**

```
<div class="alert alert-error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

**views/v_document/upload_success.php**

```
<?php $this->load->view('v_page/header_view'); ?>

    <div class="alert alert-success">Your file was successfully uploaded!</div>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
        <li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo anchor(base_url().'public/img/uploads/' . $upload_data['file_name'], 'View uploaded image') ?>
        </br>
        <?php echo anchor('upload', 'Upload another image'); ?>
    </p>

<?php $this->load->view('v_page/footer_view'); ?>
```

My program works good. I can upload images one by one, but what I want is to upload multiple images in one single click. I need that because there are lots of document that we need to upload on our web sites.

Hope to receive help from you guys.

Comment: i'm currently learning node.js and i read that they can upload multiple file, so try to study it.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is change the name of the file tag to array like

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple" class="btn btn-file"/>
```

and then you need to put the upload code into foreach as shown below

```
 foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $file)
   {
       if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file)) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            .
            .
            .

          }
    }
```

Cheers.

Comment: I have used once... do you see any problem?

Comment: I think instead of $file you need to pass $index as an argument to do_upload method

Comment: Well... could be the case... @xxxxxxz can you please verify and give the feedback

Comment: I receive this error Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: I tried to remove the $file on do_upload() and name="userfile" and it works, but it only multiplies one image. For example, I uploaded three images. The result is only the last image is uploading and it uploads twice. so if there are 3 images, 6 images have been uploaded to database.

Comment: add $index=>$file in forach and pass $index in do upload like do_upload($index)

Comment: the result is only the last image is uploading and it becomes 3. If I chooses mouse.jpg, keyboard.jpg, monitor.jpg. the output: monitor1.jpg, monitor2.jpg, monitor3.jpg

Comment: hang on a sec... I am checking something

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library... seems quicker than the other alternative.

https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

after adding what you need to do is

Change in controller :

```
//upload multiple file 

 if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("files"){
            //Code to run upon successful upload.
        }    

//get data of uploaded files

  print_r($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
```

I hope you are using codeigniter 2.x

Comment: now we are talking @Dirgh.. this seems to be perfact solution to avoid headache...

Comment: I tried to do that. The same thing happen. I think because that library is not for single click and to be able to run it, I need to create another file button. And here's the result I have 10 file upload buttons T_T

Comment: I don't think so mate... because it works fine when I checked with multiple attribute of file box